# how to trace this stack and pointer

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct test
{
    int *p;
};
typedef struct test * TESTP;
struct ex
{
TESTP *testpp;
};
typedef struct ex * EXP;
void main(void)
{
    int x=10;
    struct test t2; 
    TESTP t1=(struct test *)malloc(sizeof(struct test));
    EXP e1=(EXP)malloc(sizeof(struct ex));
    (e1->testpp)=&t1;
    t1->p=&x;
    printf("%d\n",**(e1->testpp));
}
```

I would like to trace back to value stored at pointer p(i.e., 10), by using e1. is that possible to trace that? This code edited accidentally, i am not sure this will work. if it works please show me how can i trace back to value in 'p' using 'e1'.

Comment: try to see `sp` and `push`, using disassembly. You can use breakpoints to trace each variable

Comment: are you using an ide for this?

Comment: @boxed__l:NO, am using GCC compiler;

Comment: Could you clarify the term "trace back"?  It sounds like you want advice how to dereference it, but the term "traceback" is often reserved for a stack trace useful for debugging.

Comment: Not about what you asked: Per IOS/IEC 9899:1999 section 5.1.2.2.1 1, the `main()` function must be declared as `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` "or in some other implementation-defined manner". Therefore, unless your compiler explicitly documents `void main(void)` as being valid, you're declaring `main()` incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be able to dereference a chain starting with `e1` getting to `p` eventually.

Here is how you do that:

```
printf("%d\n",*((*(e1->testpp))->p));
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I have one more doubt, lets assume
x=10,&x=2686748;
t1->p=2686748,&(t1->p)=9834160;
t1=9834160,&t1=2686740;
e1->testpp=2686740,&(e1->testpp)=9834192;
e1=9834192,&e1=2686736;;
so if i do print ***(e1->testpp) i should get 10, but i am getting an error. Whats wrong with this  ? Also there is a huge difference between the address of (x,t1,e1) and (p,testpp) why ?